# QtCreator importing makefile projects

Tags: qt-creator, makefile

have You ever tried to import classic c++/make project into QtCreator ?

Lets say I wanted to use in my gui project some library that needs to be build.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use qtcreator with makefile project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496188/use-qtcreator-with-makefile-project)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Qt Creator 2.0.1 you can only import projects using: *.cmake, *.creator, *.pro or *.qmlproject.

So convert to cmake and you can import the project into Qt Creator (Welcome tab -> Open Project...).

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone who comes by here... it nowadays is easily possible, to open an existing project in QtCreator, see:
[another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496188/use-qtcreator-with-makefile-project)