# Using CMake or Make for QTCreator 5.3

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, qt-creator

I'm trying to figure out how to use CMake or Make with QTCreator 5.3. 
In general I don't really know how to use CMake so it would be really helpful if someone could help me walk through the steps on how to use CMake and also how to make it work for QTCreator!

Right now I'm working off a Windows computer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean [QtCreator 3.3](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) (is has its own version scheme), you have to write the files with a text editor and then open them with QtCreator. For CMake there is a manual [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-project-cmake.html). For make you won't get much [support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18509489/3781684) from QtCreator.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yeah I don't know what's supposed to go in the text editor. And I've been using that same tutorial, but get stuck on the choosing the executable. My version of QT doesn't ask for an executable, it asks for the .txt and then I get an error there because it's not written correctly.