# I've imported an existing project with QtCreator. Now it's complaining "No rule to make target 'all'."

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, qt-creator

I'm migrating a Windows/OS X project to Linux and I've decided on Qt Creator 3.5.0 as my development environment. I imported my existing C++ files using "New File or Project > Import Project > Import Existing Project" but when I attempt to build I get the error

```
"No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.".
```

Searching around for answers tells me that Qt Creator isn't supposed to use a makefile for projects imported this way (the [Qt Creator manual](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-generic.html) suggests that the .includes .files and .config file perform the same function), and writing my own makefiles doesn't seem like the correct path to take. I assume something is wrong with my configuration if importing doesn't even generate a makefile for me (if it is indeed necessary to use one).

I am not sure how to proceed other than writing my own makefile in which case the Qt Creator import tool seems useless at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Import Existing Project feature is used when you want to use Qt Creator as a code editor. This is from the manual you linked:

> Generic project support allows you to use Qt Creator as a code editor. You can change the way your project is built by modifying the make command in the Projects mode under Build Settings.

And from [this](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html) page in the manual:

> Import Existing Project
>
> Import an existing project that does not use any of the supported build systems: qmake, Qbs, CMake, or Autotools. This enables you to use Qt Creator as a code editor

So using this method, Qt Creator will not generate a makefile for you. See this post for an example of how this feature is used:

[Use qtcreator with makefile project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496188/use-qtcreator-with-makefile-project)

If you want to use Qt Creator build system you can create a "Plain C++ Project" and then add your source files.

Comment: For future reference: I eventually found the functionality I was looking for by using CMake. As mentioned in this answer, QtCreator natively supports CMake projects, which also ended up being useful for generating my msvc and xcode projects.