# How to run GNUMakefiles with QtCreator

Tags: qt-creator, gnu-make

I am trying to run one of the examples related to OpenDDS within Qt Creator.
the example available which is ishapes project doesn't have any .pro file.
how can I run the project? it only have the .h, cpp and the GNUMakefile.

Comment: could you indicate which example you want to run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use qtcreator with makefile project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496188/use-qtcreator-with-makefile-project)

Comment: this is the ishape example link https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/tree/master/examples/DCPS/ishapes